# Show underlying row if aggregated row only aggregates one row Angular UI-Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using Angular UI-Grid for grouping around an ID but for my use case there are a lot of rows where the grouped row is only aggregating one row. If that's the case I would like to just show the underlying row instead of showing the grouped row which feels redundant. Is this possible.

I've tried to recreate my situation in this plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/FTjmpLejrUR3OYsAgpbQ?p=preview

Here is my columnDefs and my data

```
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
    field: "GroupId",
    grouping: { groupPriority: 0 },
  }, {
    field: "UnderlyingId"
  }, {
    field: "Name"
  },{
    field: 'someVal',
    treeAggregationType: uiGridGroupingConstants.aggregation.SUM
  }];

  $scope.myData = [{
    'UnderlyingId': 'ABC',
    'GroupId': 'Alphabet',
    'Name': 'Three Letters',
    'someVal': 4
  }, {
    'UnderlyingId': 'DEF',
    'GroupId': 'Alphabet',
    'Name': 'Some more letters',
    'someVal': 2
  }, {
    'UnderlyingId': 'GHI',
    'GroupId': 'Alphabet',
    'Name': 'Even More letters???',
    'someVal': 1
  }, {
    'UnderlyingId': '123',
    'GroupId': 'Numbers',
    'Name': 'Some numbers here',
    'someVal': 9
  }];
```

So basically (in the plnkr) instead of showing the aggregate row for numbers I would like it to just show the underlying row.

Comment: You might try editing aggregateTemplate. The documentation of ui-grid has this option but there is no effect of using it. I've also looked up in the source but it doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: I managed to achieve the desired result using finaliser functions but I ended up just changing the way I was aggregating the data instead.